# Call of Duty: Black Ops 1 freezes at the intro screen on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops

Every time I put in Black Ops 1 in my Xbox 360 and press play, it freezes at the end of the intro when the screen turns white.

It is a used game but there is no scratches or marks on the disk.

Comment: Have you tried using the disk in a different 360 to confirm there's nothing wrong with it?

Comment: Also, try this.  I had to do it for my Minecraft disc.  Change your Start-up to go to Xbox Home instead of reading from the disc.  Then try starting the game from there.  I've also had to start the Xbox with no disc in it and after it's fully loaded, I then put the disc in and have it read from Xbox Home.

Answer (score 1):

You can "bypass" this issue by renting the game and installing it to your Xbox. Once it's installed a faulty disk *should* work.

Here is the link to install a game to your Xbox: https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/system/install-play-delete-game#1e9bb50361ee488da0cbd0ea72b78d99

Answer (score 0):

It happened to us to and we left it for a couple minutes and then it loaded